# Delete 2 lines from header in txt files in a folder using vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hi im using the below macro to delete first 2 lines of txt files in a folder

```
Private Sub remove()

Dim FSO, txs, fld, fil As file, content, nLinesToSkip, i
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

nLinesToSkip = 2

fld = FSO.GetFolder("O:\New folder\")
For Each fil In fld
    If Right(fil.Name, 3) = "txt" Then

        Set txs = fil.OpenAsTextStream(1) ' 1 = for reading
        For i = 1 To nLinesToSkip
            txs.SkipLine
        Next i
        content = txs.ReadAll
        txs.Close

        Set txs = fil.OpenAsTextStream(2) ' 2 = for writing
        txs.Write content
        txs.Close

    End If
Next fil
End Sub
```

while running this script im getting type mismatch error for line 
For Each fil In fld

would appreciate if anyone can assist in solving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeeped answered, it might be easier with the Dir. 
Also, opening it with excel makes the operation slightly more simple to my sense.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim K As Integer
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

StrFile = Dir("O:\New folder\*.txt")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

       Workbooks.Open Filename:="O:\New folder\" & StrFile
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           Rows("1:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
           ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="O:\New folder\" & StrFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
           ActiveWindow.Close
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True

       StrFile = Dir

    Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

.GetFolder isn't doing what you think it is. It returns a folder object. You want the files within the folder.

Try it as,

```
Set fld = FSO.GetFolder("O:\New folder\")
For Each fil In fld.Files
    ...
Next fil
```

TBH, I don't know why you aren't using the simpler Dir with a *.txt file mask.

Answer (score 1):

To Loop through files in a folder use `DIR` as suggested by Jeeped. You may want to see this stackoverflow link

[Loop through files in a folder using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Writing/Manipulating Text file using Excel is a slower process. Here is a much faster process

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim MyFile As String

    MyFile = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.Txt"

    '~~> Read the file in an array in 1 go
    Open MyFile For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    '~~> Delete old file
    Kill MyFile

    '~~> Write to new file
    Open MyFile For Output As #1

    '~~> From 3rd line onwards
    For i = 2 To UBound(strData)
        Print #1, strData(i)
    Next i

    Close #1
End Sub
```

If you do not want to overwrite the old file then change the below lines

```
    '~~> Delete old file
    Kill MyFile

    '~~> Write to new file
    Open MyFile For Output As #1
```

I am also assuming that there are more than 2 lines in the text file. If not then you will have to handle that accordingly.